# Changing specific text in php

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

```
$url = localhost/project/index.php?letter=0&position=0&bypass=1
```

How to change ***position=0*** to ***`position=1`***?

The new `$url` value will be:

```
$url = localhost/project/index.php?letter=0&position=1&bypass=1
```

Comment: why u need to change URL? why not to overwrite the just value like `if($_GET['position'] == 0){$_GET['position'] = 1;}`?? you are using str_replace tag but not using it in your code?

Comment: use string replace

Comment: @devpro some headings and forms will be changed if I go to **position=1** from *position=0*. It's not necessary it will have 1 or 2. It can be anything..., for example here I used 1 & 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Change URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196081/php-change-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [parse-str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse-url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) approach with the help of [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php),

```
$url = "localhost/project/index.php?letter=0&position=0&bypass=1";
// fetching query paramters and save it to output variable
parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY),$output);
// changing position value
$output["position"] = 1;
// building back query string
$query = http_build_query($output);
// creating final string
echo parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH)."?".$query;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0FRW3)
**Output**:-

```
localhost/project/index.php?letter=0&position=1&bypass=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the str_replace() function to replace a specific text from string.

```
$url = str_replace('position=0','position=1',$url);
```